# Need help with problem 6(a) from Topology Without Tears

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Following is Topology Without Tears by Morris

Let A,B be a space of R with Euclidean topology
If A is the set of all rational numbers,B set of irrational number

Consider these 4 sets :

(1)A $\cap$ cl(B)
(2)cl(A)$ \cap$ B. (3)cl(A)$\cap$ cl(B)(4 ) cl(A$\cap$B)

**Prove  that no two sets are equal**

(This is last best attempt. Please upvote me.
If it is wrong, show the proof. The proof in full
has not been given to date .When I tag it I put
#proofexplanation or something similar. This implies
I want explanation. I am having a hell of time learning
it. I might not be crying, but am close to bashing my
head against the wall in agony

In my previous attempt I thought I was dealing with dense
sets since Q and R/Q are dense in R so that is how I did
it..)

**Try**

0.Q and R$\setminus$ Q are the same under closure in R

1.Since A $\cap B =\emptyset$ ,cl(A $\cap B)=\emptyset$ Furthermore A and B are dense in R.

2.(From :[Interior, closure and boundary of the sets of all rational and irrational numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283987/interior-closure-and-boundary-of-the-sets-of-all-rational-and-irrational-number))

Whenever A & B are dense disjoint subsets of a topological space **X** we have  cl(A)=X=cl(B) by Def.of being dense. Since  B$\subset A^{c}$ and A$\subset B^{c}$
it follows cl($A^{c})=X=cl(B^{c}$)

Since we have A being  the set of rationals (Q) ,B being
the set of irrationals (R\Q) and set intersection and taking compliments we get:

(i) A$\cap$cl(B) = Q $\cap$ R=Q

(ii)cl(A)$\cap $B= R $\cap$ R\Q= R\Q

(iii)= R $\cap$ R=R

(iv) ={}

Therefore none of them are equal

Comment: I think you have to tell us what $Q$ means and what $I$ means.

Comment: OK. Please edit that into the body of the question. People shouldn't need to read the comments to understand what the question is asking. And what does it mean when you put a bar over the union symbol? Do you mean $\overline{\overline A\cup\overline B}$?

Comment: Also, you have $A,B$ as subsets of $R$, but as elements of $Q,I$. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually, the whole thing is nonsense. $X$ is never defined. It is never given that $B$ is dense in $X$. Please start over, being more careful.

Comment: I rewrote the theorem to be proved. I am not to good with these proofs.@GerryMyerson

Comment: Isn't $(1)$ and (2) the same? both are $\mathbb{R}$, no? [Check](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283987/interior-closure-and-boundary-of-the-sets-of-all-rational-and-irrational-number)

Comment: I don't understand what union bar is, so I won't comment for $(4)$, but I think $(1),(2),(3) = \mathbb{R}$. But $(1),(2),(3)$ would be different if it's intersection instead of union.

Comment: Yup, then check ing with (3) and (4) should prove it

Comment: "dense" is an adjective, not an operator. Please clarify.

Comment: In topology and related areas of mathematics, a subset A of a topological space X is called dense (in X) if every point x in X either belongs to A or is a limit point of A; that is, the closure of A constitutes the whole set X
From Wikipedia

Comment: I know what the *adjective* "dense" means. What does the *operator* $\bar{A}$ mean? The closure? The set of limit points? The complement?

Comment: @larrymintz If the question is correct (that no 2 out of the 4 union are equal), then $(1) \neq (2) \neq (3) \neq (4)$. Since as you have written, $(1) = (2)$, I believe there may have been a misunderstanding on what the question is actually asking. Can you type exactly, word by word, the question?

Comment: The current statement is still incomprehensible. It's not clear whether $\bar A$ means the complement of $A$ or the closure of $A$. It's not clear what it means when you put a bar over the intersection symbol. I don't know what "according to community wiki" means. I don't know why you write $B\subset A$ when that's clearly false. You're still introducing the symbol $X$ without telling us what it means. Mathematics is about *communication*.

Comment: I got rid of the bar symbol and put cl() instead,so now the question is clear. ,I hope. I rewrote my  whole proof,given the hints.I know math is about communication. When I mentioned the “community wiki” I thought you could go to it and see what I was referring to. Morris uses URL’s to,so maybe he is not legit,< giggles >@GerryMyerson

Comment: OK, it looks much better. I still don't know what you mean by "community wiki", and I don't know how I could "go to it". I didn't see any URLs. "Since $A\cap B$ is empty, ${\rm cl\ }A\cap{\rm\ cl\ }B$ is empty" is false. But mostly what you've written looks good.

Comment: I can’t remember “community wiki “ now But I what I stated came from here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283987/interior-closure-and-boundary-of-the-sets-of-all-rational-and-irrational-number . Can I be upvoted. I spent a ton of time on it

Comment: I suspect that the users who downvoted have moved on to other things and don't know about the improvements, and other users are looking at questions that have been posted more recently and have pushed yours off the front pages. Perhaps you could be happy that you got a good answer and maybe learned a few things on the way.

Answer (score 2):

You copied the problem in the [book](https://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) badly. (Particularly, you flipped $\cap$ as $\cup$, which makes the conclusion completely wrong.)

Here is the original one (one page 78, Chapter 3):

> [image]

and the bar means "closure" (Definition 3.1.9 on page 75).

You are asking 6(a):

- The set in (i) is equal to $A$
- The set in (ii) is equal to $B$
- The set in (iii) is equal to $\mathbb{R}$
- The set in (iv) is empty.

So no two of the above four sets are equal.

---

Notes.

You would be able to understand the answer if you read the relevant section of the book carefully.

- Example 3.1.12 tells you that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$. This is also mentioned in Section 3.4.
- It is a good exercise for you to work out that the set of irrational numbers is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
- It does not make sense to write $\bar{A}\bar{\cap}\bar{B}$. A correct way to type (iv) in the problem is `$\overline{A\cap B}$`.

Comment: It does?  I know I am asking 6(a).your right .Me bad.

Comment: I never realized the fact that the closure of the empty set is the empty set. It's 4.30am and I'm giggling.

Comment: But you don’t explain how and that is what I want to know

Comment: The way you posted the question, larry, just asked for the answers. Now that you have the answers, now you tell us that's not enough – you really want the explanations. Your question needs to be rewritten from top to bottom.

Comment: Yes I read Example 3.1.12. As to third point,I didn’t know the code for it I just knew \bar As second, I will do it for R\Q. Sometimes I find it hard to see how all the theorems work together. In real/complex analysis I saw it .I am self-studying this field..

Comment: The whole post  has been rewritten. I can’t get it any better or explain myself any better @GerryMyerson